# How to fix AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip' while loading excel file in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to load one excel file in pandas but getting the below error  -

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'

I have taken below one row along with header from excel for understanding -

```
 Row ID Order ID    Order Date  Ship Date   Ship Mode   Customer ID Customer Name   Segment Country/Region  City    State   Postal Code Region  Product ID  Category    Sub-Category    Product Name    Sales   Quantity    Discount    Profit

    1   CA-2018-152156  08-11-2018  11-11-2018  Second Class    CG-12520    Claire Gute Consumer    United States   Henderson   Kentucky    42420   NorthEAST   FUR-BO-10001798 Finance Bookcases   Bush Somerset Collection Bookcase   261.96  2   0   41.9136
```

This is the entire code-

```
local_path= '../../data/RetailStore.xlsx'
out_path= '../../out/hyperstore.csv'

def load_retail_data(local_path,sheet_name):
    return pd.read_excel(
        local_path,
        header=4,
        sheet_name=sheet_name,
        parse_dates=True
    )

def clean_headers(data_frame:pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    data_frame=data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x:x.strip())
    data_frame=data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x:x.replace('\n',' '))
    data_frame=data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x:x.replace("'",' '))
    data_frame=data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x:x.replace('  ',' '))
    return data_frame

def filter_ship_mode(df):
    return df[(df[ColumnsStore.ship_mode]!= 'Standard Class') & (df[ColumnsStore.ship_mode]!='Second Class')]


def calc_retail_data(local_path,sheet_name):
    retail_data=load_retail_data(local_path,sheet_name)
    retail_clean_headers=clean_headers(retail_data)
    retail_filtered=filter_ship_mode(retail_clean_headers)
    return retail_filtered


if __name__=="__main__":
    df_retail_data=calc_retail_data(local_path,'Orders')
    df_retail_data.to_csv(out_path,index=False)
```

Comment: col_dict = dict(zip(df.columns.values,[str(col).strip().replace('\n',' ').replace("'",' ').replace('  ',' ') for col in list(df.columns.values)])) -> create col_dict and then use this dict to rename columns

Comment: where should i write this line in my code?

Comment: Solid advice above, basically your issue is with this line under `clean_headers`: `data_frame=data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x:x.strip())` --> you're trying to `strip()` the `x` value which is an integer (e.g. iterating through column numbers, not names)

Comment: @Aelarion Then what is the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your column header type to string

```py
def clean_headers(data_frame:pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
    data_frame=data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x:x.strip())
    ...
```

Or just escape the int type

```py
def clean_headers(data_frame:pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
    data_frame=data_frame.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
    # do the same thing with other header cleaning function.
    ...
```